# What is the use of tf.select

Tags: python, tensorflow

(**edited** w.r.t. @quirk's answer)

I was reading some tensorflow-code online and saw this statements:

```
threshold = tf.select(input > RLSA_THRESHOLD, positive, negative)
```

source: https://github.com/Raverss/tensorflow-RLSA-NMS/blob/master/source.py#L31

`positive` Is a tensor with just `1`'s, `negative` also of the same size with `0`'s and input is some heatmap(/tensor) of the same size (all of type `tf.float32`).

The code snippet seems reasonably advanced for me to assume that the authors would have just used `tf.cast(input > RLSA_THRESHOLD, tf.float32)` if there was no specific reason for the `tf.select(...)` expression. Especially since this would have eliminated the need for the variables `positive` and `negative`, and would save memory, as they are just expensively redundant ways of storing `0` and `1`.

Is the aforementioned `tf.select(...)` expression equivalent to `tf.cast(input > RLSA_THRESHOLD, tf.float32)`? If not, why not?

**Note:** I usually use Keras, and am sorry if I'm touching something very trivial here.

Comment: BTW, tf.select is being [deprecated](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c72d891418c326794a913cc13382c104255fe1f2/RELEASE.md) in favor of tf.where

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm, RTD(Read the docs)!

[tf.select](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/comparison_operators#select) selects elements from `positive` or `negative` tensors based on the **boolness** of the elements in the `condition` tensor.

> `tf.select(condition, t, e, name=None)`
>   **Selects elements from t or e, depending on condition.**
>   The t, and e tensors must all have the same shape, and the output will also have that shape.

(from the official docs.)

So in your case:

`threshold = tf.select(input > RLSA_THRESHOLD, positive, negative)`

`input > RLSA_THRESHOLD` will be a tensor of `bool` or logical values (`0` or `1` symbolically), which will help choose a value from either the `positive` vector or the `negative` vector.

For example, say you have a `RLSA_THRESHOLD` of 0.5 and your `input` vector is a 4-dimensional vector of real continuous values ranging from 0 to 1. Your `positive` and `negative` vectors are essentially `[1, 1, 1, 1]` and `[0, 0, 0, 0]`, respectively. `input` is `[0.8, 0.2, 0.5, 0.6]`.

`threshold` will be `[1, 0, 0, 1]`.

**NOTE:** `positive` and `negative` could be any kind of tensor as long as the dimensions agree with the `condition` tensor. Had `positive` and `negative` been, say, `[2, 4, 6, 8]` and `[1, 3, 5, 7]` respectively, your `threshold` would have been `[2, 3, 5, 8]`.

---

> The code snippet seems reasonably advanced for me to assume that the authors would have just used `input > RLSA_THRESHOLD` if there was no specific reason for the `tf.select`.

There is a very good reason for that. `input > RLSA_THRESHOLD` would simply return a tensor of logical (boolean) values. Logical values **do not** mix well with numerical values. You cannot use them for any realistic numerical computation. Had the `positive` and/or `negative` tensors been real valued, you might have required your `threshold` tensor to also have real values, in case you planned to use them further along.

---

> Is the `tf.select` equivalent to `input > RLSA_THRESHOLD`? If not, why not?

No they are not. One is a function, the other is a tensor.

I am going to give you the benefit of doubt and assume you meant to ask:

> Is the `threshold` equivalent to `input > RLSA_THRESHOLD`? If not, why not?

No they are not. As explained above, `input > RLSA_THRESHOLD` is a logical  tensor with a data type of `bool`. `threshold`, on the other hand, is a tensor with the same data type as `positive` and `negative`.

**NOTE:** You can always cast your logical tensors to numerical (or any other supported data type) tensors using any of the [casting](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops/casting) methods available in [tensorflow](/questions/tagged/tensorflow).

Comment: Thank you for explaining that functions and tensors differ, and for giving me the benefit of the doubt of already understanding that :) I admit that I could have been a bit clearer in my question. Since positive and negative are tensors with resp. 1's and 0's (as noted), the `tf.select` construct seems equivalent to `>`, except for (as you stated) the result type. Therefore I was wondering whether there is a reason to use `tf.select` instead of `tf.cast`. I will edit the question to explicitly state this.

Comment: @Herbert I don't judge. ;)

Comment: I still have to admit that I could have played around with Tensorflow longer, it's just that I have rarely used it and new things can feel scary. Reading the `tf.select` documentation suggested that `tf.cast` was a more efficient alternative for this use case, and this confused me, assuming the authors of the code knew what they were doing.

Comment: The TF library mutates *very* rapidly. So many breaking API changes. There is a tiny chance that `tf.cast` was not around or did what it does now, when that example was written. Or maybe the author was not well versed with their own API. Sometimes simplicity trumps lucidity in code. Sometimes it is the other way round.

Comment: Well, I would think `tf.cast` is more lucid than `tf.select` in expressing casting booleans to floats. Most importantly, I now know that my intuition seemed right. Thank you!

Comment: As of Release 1.0 `tf.select` is gone, now use `tf.where`. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/64edd34ce69b4a8033af5d217cb8894105297d8a/RELEASE.md

Answer (score 2):

Best way you can understand it is by trying it out yourself:

```
In [86]: s = tf.InteractiveSession()

In [87]: inputs = tf.random_uniform([10], 0., 1.)

In [88]: positives = tf.ones([10])

In [89]: negatives = tf.zeros([10])    

In [90]: s.run([inputs, tf.select(inputs > .5, positives, negatives)])
Out[90]: 
[array([ 0.13187623,  0.77344072,  0.29853749,  0.29245567,  0.53489852,
         0.34861541,  0.15090156,  0.40595055,  0.34910154,  0.24349082], dtype=float32),
 array([ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.], dtype=float32)]
```

For every value > `0.5` in tensor `inputs` you'll get a `1.` at the same index, otherwise the value is `0.`.

The result of `inputs > .5` is a tensor of booleans (`True` for values that meet the condition, `False` otherwise).

```
In [92]: s.run(inputs > .5)
Out[92]: array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```